# implementing multiple string replace() using lambda function

Tags: python

I've found tons of solutions doing exactly what I'm trying to do WITHOUT lambda...but I'm learning lambda today...

I have a string `stri` and I'm trying to replace some characters in `stri` that are all stored in a dictionary.

`bad_chars={"\newline":" ","\n": " ", "\b":" ", "\f":" ", "\r":" ", "\t":" ", "\v":" ", "\0x00":" "}` and then I want to print `stri` out all pretty and empty of all of these ugly characters.  My current code print's `stri` many many times.

`format_ugly = lambda stri: [ stri.replace(i,j) for i,j in bad_chars.iteritems()]`

Is there a way to make it print once, and with only 1 lambda function?

Comment: Why does your code print `stri` many many times ? Print it once after calling the lambda-function.

Comment: It print's `stri` once for every item in the dictionary, with 1 of the characters changed at most (it looks like it prints every time it iterates my for loop after only make 1 change to the string).

Comment: `"\newline"` is the bad character `'\n'` - which you already replace - followed by `'ewline'` - which are totally ordinary letters that shouldn't be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do it that easily and if you could a `lambda` function is still not designed for your use case.

Multiple replacements like that are done using a regular `for` loop statement, and a `lambda` is limited to a single expression. If you have to use a function, use a normal function – it's entirely equivalent to a lambda function except that it's not limited to a single expression.

If you really must know how to do it in a single expression, you have three choices:

1) If you use `unicode` strings (or Python 3), and limit your bad substrings to single characters (i.e. remove `"\newline"`), you can use the `unicode.translate` method.

```
bad_chars = {u"\n": u" ", u"\b": u" ", u"\f": u" ", u"\r": u" ", u"\t": u" ", u"\v": u" ", u"\x00": u" "}
bad_chars_table = dict((ord(k), v) for k, v in bad_chars.iteritems())
translator = lambda s: s.translate(bad_chars_table)
print translator(u"here\nwe\tgo")
```

2) Use regular expressions:

```
   translator = lambda s: re.sub(r'[\n\b\f\r\t\v\x00]', ' ', s)
```

3) You can use `reduce` which can be used to reduce a sequence using a binary operation, essentially repeatedly calling a function of two arguments with the current value and an element of the sequence to get the next value.

```
translator = lambda s: reduce(lambda x, (from, to): x.replace(from, to), bad_chars.iteritems(), s)
```

As you can see, the last solution is much more difficult to understand than:

```
def translator(s):
    for original, replacement in bad_chars.iteritems():
        s = s.replace(original, replacement)
    return s
```

And both solutions do the same thing. It's often better to program for the end, not for the means. For an arbitrary problem a comprehensible single-expression solution wouldn't exist at all.

Comment: There is also `translate` for Python 2 strings.

Comment: good advice to program for the end.  Ill write that one down.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to you can force a lambda function into it:

```
print ''.join(map(lambda x: bad_chars.get(x, x), stri))
```

But really there's absolutely no need to use a lambda function here. All you need is:

```
print ''.join(bad_chars.get(x, x) for x in stri)
```

This solution is also linear time (ie O(n)) whereas all the other solutions are potentially quadratic as they involve scanning the entire string to replace each value O(n*m) where m is the size of the `bad_chars` dict.

Example:

```
bad_chars= {"\newline":" ","\n": " ", "\b":" ", "\f":" ", "\r":" ", "\t":" ", "\v":" ", "\0x00":" "}
stri = "a \b string\n with \t lots of \v bad chars"
print ''.join(bad_chars.get(x, x) for x in stri)
```

Ouptut:

```
a   string  with   lots of   bad chars
```

Comment: oh my gosh.  Im going to read up on get.  Very powerful solution, thanks.  I guess I should read more about when lambda functions should be used instead of try to solve arbitrary problems

Comment: This is __great__, just because it's so different than the way the other answerers (and I) were thinking. I wish I could upvote it twice. It might even have good performance, since the dict lookups are fast, and you only traverse the string once. You could speed it up by doing `get = bad_chars.get` too, so you wouldn't have to do the `getattr` step every time.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't produce a list of the values. Your code produces a list of values with the original text with only one character replaced (one per version). Instead operate on the result of one entry and pass it for the next. This is pretty much what reduce does:

```
replaced = reduce(lambda stri, r: stri.replace(r[0], r[1]), bad_chars.iteritems(), original)
```

this is roughly equivalent to:

```
stri.replace(r0[0], r0[1]).replace(r1[0], r1[1]).replace(...)
```

where `r0..rn` are the values from `bad_chars.iteritems()`.

Comment: This looks good....but Im still lost.  Ill muck with your code for a while and see if I figure it all out.  Thanks

Comment: If you want it to be a lambda expression, just prepend `lambda original, bad_chars: ` to that and call it as `replaced(original, bad_chars)`.